# How do I identify the SQL server brand via SQL queries

Tags: query, relational-theory, syntax, database-theory

A 3rd party API exposes a endpoint which accepts "SQL" queries. Their examples are simple `SELECT` statements, however I want to write more complicated queries.

They do not specify which SQL brand they are using, which means I don't know the exact syntax I should be following.

How can I identify the SQL brand (SQL Server, MySQL, Azure SQL, Postgres, etc) with one or more SQL queries (no command line access, file permissions, etc)?

Comment: How do you know they just pass-thru the query statements? Most likely they do some sanity checking, filtering and translations before querying their data store. They most likely only support a small subset of SQL.

Answer (score 6):

Go by elimination. Failing `select @@version` will eliminate both SQL Server and MySQL; failing `select version()` will eliminate both Postgres and MySQL; etc.

Examples of such queries have been helpfully compiled by Jack Douglas, the fine gentleman behind [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Comment: Do you want to add Oracle to your list? Per https://portswigger.net/web-security/sql-injection/examining-the-database, it's `SELECT * FROM v$version`.

Answer (score 0):

Just ask the service provider.